# Exposed filter of a view embedded in a panel overriding a node form triggers node submission. How to prevent this?

Tags: 7, panels, forms, views

I have a panel overriding the node/add form of a custom content-type in one pane and a view listing some nodes including 2 exposed filters to reduce the results of that list in another pane.

Both, the form and the view show up as i want, but if i use the exposed filters the node gets submitted instead of filtering the view.

How can i prevent this? Is there some way to do this step by step?

Drupal 7, latest dev-versions of Views and Panels.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The little module i found and installed is doing a great job so far. I will now close this by answering my own question.

The problem was solved with [this module](https://github.com/Itangalo/Node-creation-block--Drupal-7-).

> The Form Block module for Drupal (http://drupal.org/project/formblock)
>   allows displaying user registration forms, node forms and some other
>   forms in blocks. Unfortunately it was not available for Drupal 7 at
>   the time of writing, which prompted me to write this module.
>
> It provides one block for each node type, displaying the node type's
>   creation form. It respects user permissions, meaning that it will not
>   display the creation form if you are not allowed to create the node.
>
> The module was created to allow using nodes as contact forms in Drupal
>   7. I have no plans on spending very much time on this module – have a look at Form Block if you want a long-term solution.

UPDATE: The Form Block Module now has a stable release for D7 and works well for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, what i have dug up so far is that the "form" html tag goes missing when the view exposed filter form is rendered within a node form. I am still trying to fix the issue as i haven't figured out why. I will update you if i get any further on this.

Comment: I resolved this with http://github.com/Itangalo/Node-creation-block--Drupal-7-